# Sed - Fixing an sql insert stament with single quote in value

Tags: sql, unix, sed, awk

I am asked to help with a UNIX script that deploys database objects with or without data from 1 machine and/or environment with another. The problem is that some columns have CHAR data with single quotes. Only these single quotes need to be converted to 2 single quotes. I was thinking of using sed or awk, but I can't figure it out. Anyone got any ideas?
example:

```
INSERT INTO SQL_ERROR_MESSAGE (SQL_Error_Cd,Error_Text) VALUES (5492,'The argument for an INOUT/OUT parameter '%VSTR'  is invalid.');
```

becomes

```
INSERT INTO SQL_ERROR_MESSAGE (SQL_Error_Cd,Error_Text) VALUES (5492,'The argument for an INOUT/OUT parameter ''%VSTR''  is invalid.');
```

Thanks for your support.

Comment: It can be pretty tricky to find the regex to do so. What about changing the single quote for a double quote in the CHAR text? Hence, the single quote within the text will work fine. It is just a suggestion to make it easier...

Comment: In English - how do you know which quotes in your input should be doubled? Don't say "it's around CHAR data" unless you want to limit the answers you get to people who know exactly what "CHAR data" means in your domain. It'd also help if you gave a couple more sample input and expected output lines, e.g. showing multiple occurrences of `'`s that you DO and DON'T want to double up.

Answer (score 0):

If you are rather certain about the format of your `INSERT` statement, this might work for you:

```
sed "s/\([^']\+'[^']\+\)\('\)\([^']\+\)'\(.*\)/\1\2\2\3\2\2\4/" INPUTFILE
```

But I'd recommend to check the output :-)

Basically it captures everything till the second(!) `'` (in `\1`), then captures the 2nd `'` (`\2`) - that's not needed, I just wrote it this way ... -, in `\3` the string in between the `'`s which should be escaped, and finally the remaining part of the string (`\4`), and uses the saved entries in the replacement.

Exapmle output (Linux, GNU sed):

```
$ sed "s/\([^']\+'[^']\+\)\('\)\([^']\+\)'\(.*\)/\1\2\2\3\2\2\4/"
INPUT LINE #=> INSERT INTO SQL_ERROR_MESSAGE (SQL_Error_Cd,Error_Text) VALUES (5492,'The argument for an INOUT/OUT parameter '%VSTR'  is invalid.');
OUTPUT LINE #=> INSERT INTO SQL_ERROR_MESSAGE (SQL_Error_Cd,Error_Text) VALUES (5492,'The argument for an INOUT/OUT parameter ''%VSTR''  is invalid.');
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, but it doesn't seem to work. I forgot to mention that it's a HP-UX server.

Comment: In that case I'd recommend, reading the docs for the available `sed`. My solution might give you a starting point.